# SlowCheetah not recognizing ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file

Tags: silverlight-5.0, slowcheetah

I'm working on a Silverlight 5 application, trying to use SlowCheetah to get my xml transformations to happen during the build process, so that it's only done during the deployment part of the build.  My issue is that, although my "release" folder is getting the transformed file, when I release the code, the xap file isn't recognizing the transformed file and is bringing in the base *.ClientConfig file.

I've tried Len Charest's [post](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5/view/Reviews/2) without success.

Has anyone overcome this?

Comment: [I have a workaround for that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15776129/1268570)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm no longer at that job, but will forward this on to my former manager and have him implement/test.  Thanks @Jupaol